# read image path from file share and store in table storage azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-files

I'm able to upload the image in the Azure file share using below code.

```
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = ConnectionString.GetConnectionString();
            CloudFileClient cloudFileClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();             
            CloudFileShare fileShare = cloudFileClient.GetShareReference("sampleimage");
           if (await fileShare.CreateIfNotExistsAsync())
            {
                await fileShare.SetPermissionsAsync(
                    new FileSharePermissions
                    {

                    });
            }
            //fileShare.CreateIfNotExists();

            string imageName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "-" + Path.GetExtension(imageToUpload.FileName);
            CloudFile cloudFile = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetFileReference(imageName);
            cloudFile.Properties.ContentType = imageToUpload.ContentType;

            await cloudFile.UploadFromStreamAsync(imageToUpload.InputStream);

            imageFullPath = cloudFile.Uri.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return imageFullPath;
```

Here is how I'm trying to read the file path: [Before insertinginto a table]

```
public class ReadFileSharePath
{
    string Path = null;
    public string ReadFilePath()
    {

        try
        {
            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = ConnectionString.GetConnectionString();
            CloudFileClient cloudFileClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
            CloudFileShare fileShare = cloudFileClient.GetShareReference("sampleimage");
            if (fileShare.Exists())
            {
                CloudFileDirectory rootdir = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();

                CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootdir.GetDirectoryReference("sampleimage");

                if (sampleDir.Exists())
                {
                    // Get a reference to the file we created previously.
                    CloudFile file = sampleDir.GetFileReference("90e94676-492d-4c3c-beb2-1d8d48044e4e-.jpg");

                    // Ensure that the file exists.
                    if (file.Exists())
                    {
                        // Write the contents of the file to the console window.
                        //Console.WriteLine(file.DownloadTextAsync().Result);
                        Path = file.DownloadTextAsync().Result.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        return Path;

    }

}
```

However, this if condition

> if (sampleDir.Exists())

is getting failed.And, the control is not entering into loop.

I would like to store the path of file share in the Azure table storage. I would like to get partition key and row key. How to achieve this ? any link or suggestion would help? Thanks.

Comment: `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` are user defined values that is it is something that you decide.

Comment: Understood. However,how to store the path of file share in the Azure table storage?

Comment: Please take a look at the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet#add-an-entity-to-a-table. Essentially what you would do is change your model and have a member called `FileUrl` or something in that model.

Comment: @AskMe, please check if you have the `sampleimage` file directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gaurav said, after you return imageFullPath with above code, you could use following code to store path in table storage.

```
void SavePath(string fullpath)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

            // Create the table client.
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

            // Create the CloudTable object that represents the "people" table.
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("people");

            // Create a new customer entity.
            CustomerEntity customer1 = new CustomerEntity("joey", "cai");
            customer1.path = fullpath;


            // Create the TableOperation object that inserts the customer entity.
            TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(customer1);

            // Execute the insert operation.
            table.Execute(insertOperation);
        }
        public class CustomerEntity : TableEntity
        {
            public CustomerEntity(string lastName, string firstName)
            {
                this.PartitionKey = lastName;
                this.RowKey = firstName;
            }

            public CustomerEntity() { }

            public string path { get; set; }

        }
```

Note: The fullpath is the imageFullPath that you have returned.

**Edit**:
Entities map to C# objects by using a custom class derived from TableEntity. **To add an entity to a table, create a class that defines the properties of your entity.**

The above code defines an entity class that uses the customer's first name as the row key and last name as the partition key. Together, an entity's partition and row key uniquely identify it in the table.  Entities to be stored in tables must be of a supported type, for example derived from the **TableEntity** class.

And the above code shows the creation of the `CloudTable` object and then a `CustomerEntity` object. To prepare the operation, a `TableOperation` object is **created to insert the customer entity into the table**. Finally, the operation is executed by calling `CloudTable.Execute`.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet#add-an-entity-to-a-table).

Update:

> As I understand the Row and Partition key is unique hence error.

So, when you insert the second entity into the table, it use the same Partition key and Row key. So you could keep the partition key the same and change the row key value.
Change the following code to the above:

```
CustomerEntity customer1 = new CustomerEntity("joey", "cai"+Guid.NewGuid());
customer1.path = fullpath;
TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(customer1);
table.Execute(insertOperation);
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Let me give a try...Could you please give small explanation of your answer?

Comment: To add an entity to a table, create a class that defines the properties of your entity. The above code defines an entity class that uses the customer's first name as the row key and last name as the partition key. Together, an entity's partition and row key uniquely identify it in the table. To insert an entity to table, TableOperation object is created. Finally, the operation is executed by calling CloudTable.Execute. And in Entity, you need to storage the pathUrl, so I customer the Entity.

Comment: @JoeyCai It would be helpful if you edit your answer and include details provided in your last comment there only. I think these are important details not suited in comments section.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. However, I'm getting error "the remote server returned an error (409) conflict" when I'm trying to insert 2nd image. As I understand the Row and Partition key is unique hence error. I don't want to use "InsertOrReplace" method. So, how to insert multiple images paths into a table storage?

Comment: I have update my reply. You could use RowKey+Guid.NewGuid() to insert multiple image paths into a table storage.